# Flex Center first column

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Question: how to make that 1 column is center and after it rest of the columns.

Now the whole grid is centered

Comment: Please add a bit more details.

Comment: @Kameron added image

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-left: calc(50% - 40%);` on `flex-container`. This way it is always dynamic with the `calc`. Then you can set `width: 10%;` on your `flex-item`'s.

[image]

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 40%);
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok how about when item is 150px on full width, below 1200px , the item is 120px and below 600 item is 100px how about then ?

Answer (score -1):

I got another solution for you ..

---

Here is without gap. You can play with **width** to resize boxes

```
.flex-item{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.half-container{
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.flex-container {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  /* gap: 1rem; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  
}

.flex-item p{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  
}

.flex-item::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="half-container"></div>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is with gap

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.half-container{
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.flex-container {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  
}

.flex-item p{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  
}

.flex-item::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="half-container"></div>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
          <p>4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there must be easier approach like two flexes, first in the center and second after

Comment: there will be tons of approaches @kosnkov

Comment: your solution based on static 100px, how about when the size of containter depens on screen resultion

Comment: @kosnkov the quality of answers you receive depends on the quality of the question you ask.